# Invalid prop `component` supplied to `ForwardRef`

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What is the root of the problem and how I can solve it?

```
Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` supplied to `ForwardRef`, expected one of type [string, function].
```

I had a custom `Box`.

```js
const Box: FC<any> = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const {
    component: Component = 'div',
    className,
    margin,
    position = 'relative',
    top,
    bottom,
    left,
    right,
    justify,
    align,
    padding,
    direction,
    inject,
    flex,
    width,
    wrap,
    fullWidth = false,
    flexGrow,
    flexBasis,
    flexShrink,
    order,
    style: propStyles,
    children,
    danger,
    serverName,
    ...rest
  } = props
// some code
Box.propTypes = {
  component: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.func]),
// some props 

}
```

The error appear when I tried to pass a component to the `component` prop, but all tests pass successfully.

Comment: In react, `Component` can also be a class aka class components. You need to include that type in your proptypes as well

Comment: yea I think that should work

Comment: @smac89, [OFFTOP]: Idk, how to upvote your comment, so just ty

Comment: To any user, who stuck with the same problem: I changed `PropTypes.func` to `PropTypes.object`